# Oracle SQL select loop based on other select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, loops, for-loop

I would like to perform a series of select statements based on the values returned from an initial select statement.  Essentially loop through the original values and using the value as a criteria for a new select.

Some pseudo code of what I am trying to do (how I would write this in shell...):

```
for location in `select places from tablename where XYZ`
do
   select new_field from tablename where location = '$location';
done
```

Here are the selects I really want to run.

Get me a list of Racks:

```
select   regexp_substr("MYTABLE"."Serial_Number" ,'[^ ]+', 1, 3) as "Racks"
  from   "MYTABLE" "MYTABLE" 
 where   "MYTABLE"."Data_Center" ='SOMEPLACE' 
   and   "MYTABLE"."Device_Type" ='RACK'
   and   "MYTABLE"."Serial_Number" not like '%WAREHOUSE%'
```

Print who should own the rack based on count of devices:

```
select count(*) as count, LOB 
 from    "MYTABLE" "MYTABLE" 
 where   "MYTABLE"."Data_Center" ='SOMEPLACE' 
   and   GRID_LOCATION = '$RACK_from_above' and rownum <= 1 group by LOB order by count desc;
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can readily combine these into a single query:

```
with thelist as (
    select   regexp_substr("MYTABLE"."Serial_Number" ,'[^ ]+', 1, 3) as "Racks"
      from   "MYTABLE" "MYTABLE" 
     where   "MYTABLE"."Data_Center" ='SOMEPLACE' 
       and   "MYTABLE"."Device_Type" ='RACK'
       and   "MYTABLE"."Serial_Number" not like '%WAREHOUSE%'
)
select count(*) as count, LOB 
from    "MYTABLE" "MYTABLE" 
where   "MYTABLE"."Data_Center" ='SOMEPLACE' and
      GRID_LOCATION in (select racks from thelist) and
      rownum <= 1
group by LOB
order by count desc;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, I can definitely follow your logic on how this is written, but I get an error when I attempt to run it (I substituted in the proper table name and data center name):  `ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`.  Any ideas on where the error might be?

Comment: @nvrmore100 . . . I left out an "and" statement.  I'm more prone to such errors when I adopt someone else's indentation style.  Oh well.  This should perhaps fix the syntax problem.

Answer (score 2):

Simply join the table to itself (using 2 different aliases)

```
select count(1) as count, MYTABLE1.LOB, MYTABLE1.GRID_LOCATION  
from    "MYTABLE" "MYTABLE1" , "MYTABLE" "MYTABLE2"   
where   MYTABLE1.Data_Center ='SOMEPLACE'    
 and   MYTABLE1.GRID_LOCATION = regexp_substr(MYTABLE2.Serial_Number ,'[^ ]+', 1, 3)
 and   MYTABLE1.rownum <= 1
 and   MYTABLE2.Data_Center ='SOMEPLACE'
 and   MYTABLE2.Device_Type ='RACK'
 and   MYTABLE2.Serial_Number not like '%WAREHOUSE%'
group by MYTABLE1.LOB, MYTABLE1.GRID_LOCATION
order by count desc;
```

Note that I added grid location to the group by and select clauses for (what seems to me) obvious reasons - if that's unclear you can ask as a separate question.

Comment: Hi DVK.  Can you explain how this is written a bit for me?  I am very new to SQL...  Are you creating a pair of temporary tables (1 & 2) based off of my original table "MYTABLE"?  When I run this inserting the proper table name and data center, I get the following error: `ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification`.  Thanks.